# What is the name of this percussion instrument?

Tags: instruments, percussion

I'm listening to the song ["There Goes the Fear" by the Doves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERulrmjfucc&t=6m15s). There's a peculiar percussive instrument that fades in starting around the 6:15 mark and then becomes the foremost percussive instrument through the end of the song. It's certainly not an instrument I've encountered in all my time in an orchestra or band. That being the case, I have no idea what it looks like. The instrument has a "pitch" of sorts, but it's clearly not meant to play any kind of tune, and all the times I've heard this instrument (including this instance) it seems to modulate between two or three pitches in rhythm at the player's discretion. It has an almost "jungle" feel to it; like a monkey "ooking" and "eeking."

I even remember this instrument being available on my old, cheap Yamaha keyboard as one of the percussion instruments, and two different pitches were available, but there was no text label for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [friction drum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction_drum). It has a handle attached to the drumhead,  when you slide your [grip along this handle it causes the drumhead to vibrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVOm268uQkw).